# How execute a command in batch-file if errorlevel is not zero?

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I created a simple batch file which would enable me to connect to the internet.
I made it this way- If the connection is successful a message is displayed stating "connection successful" using VBscript and display a message stating "connection failure" if the connection is not established. I made this using if-else statements and errorlevel command, but I am not able to display the failure message using 'errorlevel == 1' command.I mean that if there was an error in the connection process the success message is displayed instead of failure message.

Here's the code in my batch file.

```
rasdial "TATA PHOTON+" internet

@echo off
if ERRORLEVEL == 0 (echo MSGBOX "Connection successfully established to TATA PHOTON+" > %temp%\TEMPmessage.vbs
call %temp%\TEMPmessage.vbs
del %temp%\TEMPmessage.vbs /f /q)
else if ERRORLEVEL == 1 (echo MSGBOX "ERROR: Unable to establish connection" > %temp%\TEMPmessage.vbs
call %temp%\TEMPmessage.vbs
del %temp%\TEMPmessage.vbs /f /q
)
```

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
if errorlevel == 0 do-something
```

is not valid syntax.  Based on some quick tests, it would appear that the command processor is reinterpreting it as

```
if errorlevel 0 do-something
```

which means "if errorlevel is *at least* 0 do something".

Instead, I recommend

```
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 do-something
```

Using the percent-signs version allows you to test for equality and also correctly handles the case where the return value is negative.

Answer (score 2):

`if errorlevel == 1` compares the string `errorlevel` to the string `1` and for some reason finds they don't match.

You need either

```
if %errorlevel% == 1 dosomething
```

or

```
if errorlevel 1 dosomething
```

Where the second method will execute *dosomething* if `errorlevel` is 1 **or is greater than 1**

consequently, `if errorlevel 0 dosomething` will **always** dosomething.(but there are ways of setting `errorlevel to a negative amount. This is not normally encountered)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like that :

```
rasdial "TATA PHOTON+" internet
@echo off
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    Goto :sucess
) else (
    GoTo :Fail
)
::****************************************************************************************
:sucess
(echo MSGBOX "Connection successfully established to TATA PHOTON+",VbInformation,"Connection successfully established to TATA PHOTON+" > %temp%\TEMPmessage.vbs
call %temp%\TEMPmessage.vbs
del %temp%\TEMPmessage.vbs /f /q
)
Exit /b
::****************************************************************************************
:Fail
(echo MSGBOX "ERROR: Unable to establish connection",vbCritical,"ERROR: Unable to establish connection" > %temp%\TEMPmessage.vbs
call %temp%\TEMPmessage.vbs
del %temp%\TEMPmessage.vbs /f /q
)
Exit /b
::****************************************************************************************
```